# Display a pandas data frame with Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a nice way to display data frames with Bokeh? I have a bunch of table-based text I'd like to display and dynamically update along with some graphs, but I haven't found a good way to do this yet.

Answer (score 19):

You should take a look into bokeh.models.widgets.DataTable

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#data-table

Example:

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, vform

output_file("data_table.html")

data = dict(
        dates=[date(2014, 3, i+1) for i in range(10)],
        downloads=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    )
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date", formatter=DateFormatter()),
        TableColumn(field="downloads", title="Downloads"),
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

show(vform(data_table))
```

You could exchange data with your own DataFrame like:

```
data = dict(df[['first', 'second']])
```

If the column names differ please change columns variable to:

```
columns = [
        TableColumn(field="first", title="First"),
        TableColumn(field="second", title="Second"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 15):

To convert a Pandas DataFrame `DF` into a table in Bokeh, you could use a list comprehension to set the table up:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn

Columns = [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in DF.columns] # bokeh columns
data_table = DataTable(columns=Columns, source=ColumnDataSource(DF)) # bokeh table

show(data_table)
```

This assumes you want the Bokeh columns to match the DF column names, but that is easily modified if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use bokeh.models.widgets.DataTable:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#data-table